# Extracting data from RDF in php?

Tags: php, mysql, rdf

I'm a bit lost.
I'd like to extract specific parts of rdf files to build sql tables with.

Here's the start of the rdf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xml:base="http://rdf.insee.fr/geo/2011/"
    xmlns:geo="http://rdf.insee.fr/geo/"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://rdf.insee.fr/geo/2011/cantons-31-2011.rdf">
        <dc:title xml:lang="fr">Cantons et communes du département de la Haute-Garonne (31)</dc:title>
        <dc:date>2011-02-21</dc:date>
        <dc:publisher>INSEE</dc:publisher>
        <dc:format>XML-RDF</dc:format>
    </rdf:Description>

    <geo:Canton rdf:about="CAN_3101">
        <geo:code_canton>3101</geo:code_canton>
        <geo:nom xml:lang="fr">Aspet</geo:nom>
        <geo:chef-lieu rdf:resource="COM_31020"/>
        <geo:subdivision>
            <geo:Commune rdf:about="COM_31011">
                <geo:code_commune>31011</geo:code_commune>
                <geo:nom xml:lang="fr">Arbas</geo:nom>
                <geo:voisin rdf:resource="COM_31011" />
                <geo:voisin rdf:resource="COM_31140" />
                <geo:voisin rdf:resource="COM_31191" />
                <geo:voisin rdf:resource="COM_31236" />
                <geo:voisin rdf:resource="COM_31357" />
            </geo:Commune>
        </geo:subdivision>
```

I'd like to extract each geo:code_canton with it's geo:nom xml:lang="fr" to put them in s table.
Then extract geo:code_commune and it's geo:nom xml:lang="fr"to put them in another table with the geo:code_canton

I need them to reference each canton and every city in that canton.

Any help or hint ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, read the manual of XML manipulation. `DOMElement` and `DOMNode` are your friends. Then read the manual of Database Extensions. `PDO` and/or `Mysqli` are your friends and then do the work.

Comment: Thanks Al_ I already know this song called "RTFM".
I might have not expressed myself clearly, I was just asking for help or hints if anybody reading this had already done something similar.

Comment: Actually, starting to parse RDF/XML from scratch using an XML parser is not a very good suggestion. Using an RDF library that contains an RDF/XML parser and a SPARQL engine makes more sense.

Comment: Oh and regarding the provided RDF example: The `<dc:format>` bit should say “RDF/XML”, not “XML-RDF” ;-)

Comment: cygri I managed to get what I wanted :)

Comment: Somewhat un-related, but depending on what you're doing w/ the 'sql tables' you're building from the RDF, you might just consider using an actual RDF database, since you know, they're good at storing and querying RDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gone with [www.aelius.com/njh/easyrdf/](http://www.aelius.com/njh/easyrdf/)